# Use XSLT to read from one HTML source and create a new HTML page?

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to learn how to use XSLT to read from one HTML source and create a new HTML page. I know some about using XSLT to read from a XML file and create a new HTML page, but the other way is new for me and I can't find any useful tutorials about the subject.

I'm loking for some basic knowledge about this to be able to start, but I don't know how to think and use XSLT to e.g select divs and it's content from the source HTML and create a new HTML and perhaps create a new page without the head tag and so on.

Preciate some basic help or a good links about this subject. Thanks! :)

Hi again! This is my task and problem that I need some help to solve, if it's possible?! I have one XHTML document that use a CSS stylesheet. Let's call the XHTML document for "B". I want to create a new XHTML document, let's call that "A", and use some of the divs from "B" on "A" with a new CSS stylesheet. It's like if someone click on "B" they would come to "A" instead. Hmmm, and I don't know where to start and I don't know if this is possible? How do I add a CSS stylesheet to the XSLT code? Maybe no one understand what I'm talking about, but don't hesitate to ask. Preciate all help that I can get to solve this task! Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: XSLT can only work with well-formed XML. So the first step is always to convert your HTML to XHTML. Tools like `tidy` can do this for you.

Comment: This must be done dynamically at runtime on the browser side?

Answer (score 1):

When converting from XHTML to (X)HTML, from the point of view of a processor, you might want first to avoid the external resolution of the parse phase caused by the doctype, as it can be source of runtime errors.

In such a case you should see if your processor supports any options to disable that or you may need to remove the doctype declaration from the input document directly.

For example in **msxsl** you can use the `xe` options to disable external doctype resolutions:

```
> msxsl test_i.xml test_t.xsl -o test_o.xml -xe
```

---

From the point of view of **XSLT 1.0**, your xhtml is just an XML document with a specific namespace. For instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Foo</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

To be able to convert this to other XHTML document your XSLT must:

- declare the correct default namespace and prefix
- declare the correct output and doctype

You will access the elements in the input document using the defined prefix. For example this transform just add an header to the input document:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    exclude-result-prefixes="x">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" 
        doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" 
        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="x:body">
        <xsl:copy>
            <h1>Foo Title</h1>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notice:

- declaration of the namespace prefix `xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` allows you to correctly select the elements in the input document which are qualified in the xhtml namespace.
- declaration of default namespace `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html"` prevents the generation of unwanted empty namespaces `xmlns=""` in the output document.
- the usage of `exclude-result-prefixes` allows you to exclude the declaration of the xhtml namespace in the output document elements explicitely declared in the XSLT.

---

From the point of view of **XSLT 2.0**, it's really much simple. You can declare the XPath default namespace, thus getting rid of the prefixes. The stylesheet declaration will be:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Is this code necessary: xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    exclude-result-prefixes="x">

What does the line with match="node()|@*"> do?

Comment: @user: I have expanded the XSLT 1.0 section of my answer to better explain namespaces. The template you are referring to is known as _identity rule_ and you will find a lot of examples here in SO explaining what it means.

Comment: How do I do to run your code above and see the output result?

Comment: My task is to use XSLT to remove som unwanted DIVs and add new style to some DIVs from an external XHTML document. Is this really the right way and what is the point to "rebuild" an XHTML document with XSLT? I'm just trying to deliver something to the person who gave me the task.

Comment: Please consider of posting new questions :)

Comment: I've added an answer to this question, despite of you already having accepted an answer, because I thought the answer and comments above were not real answers. If your question is not resolved yet, you should unaccept the answer above and expand your original question with more details; OR create a new question.

Comment: Why did you accept the answer if you still have questions? ;-)

Comment: Well I accepted it because that was the only answer at that time, and I did't tought there would be any more. It gave me some extra knowledge. Your answer was highly preciated, but I'm still searching for clues how to solve my task. I have removed the the "accept" sign now. I preciate all help I can get.

Comment: Ok. Now you should _edit_ your original question, expanding it and trying to be much clear as possible. This will positionate your question on the top XSLT active questions, thus making it visible to SO community. This is good for your question. Better your question is, and better answers you will receive.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stackoverflow!

You may in in one of two situations:

- Your HTML file is in fact an XHTML file - in this case, nothing changes!  HTML is simply a particular type of XML, and you can use all the normal techniques for processing it.  There's nothing special about HTML input from the perspective of XSLT: learn XSLT and you can apply that to HTML just fine (of course, feel free to ask specific questions here!)
- Your HTML file is not XHTML, and cannot be parsed by an xml parser.  In this case, you'll need to convert the syntax to XML, or use a parser the represents the HTML as an XML tree.  HTML Tidy can convert HTML to XHTML (and there are many flavors of it), and for example HTML Agility Pack can parse HTML and represent it as XML (note that HTML agility pack doesn't support xml namespaces, so if you have any of those in your input, you'll need to remove them first).

Comment: Hmmm, thanks! The source file is a XHTML file, so perhaps it's not that difficult.

Comment: So if I have a XHTML document with a <div id="top"><div id="sub"></div></div> would that be <xsl: value-of select="top/sub" /> in XSLT to display the content in the <div id="sub"> ?? Am I thinking right?