# Select DIV tag with XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xhtml

I'm trying to create a new XHTML document from another XHTML document. I only want to use some of the DIV tags in the old XHTML document, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. To start, if I want to select a special DIV tag with ID = mbContent, could I use

```
<xsl:template match="x:div[@id='mbContent']">
```

This DIV tag contains other DIVs and content like images and so on. How do I do if I want to use the same CSS style that is applied to the content? Is there a way to copy the CSS style or do I have to add new CSS style and how do I do that? Since the new XHTML document is going to be part of antother XHTML, I cant use HEAD tag and put a reference to the CSS stylesheet that way.

Hmm, but if I use the CSS stylesheet that is going to be in the HEAD of the main XHTML documnet, perhaps I could apply that CSS styles to this DIV, or? How do I apply styles in the new XHTML document?

I'm a little bit confused, but I hope my question isn't to confusing?! :)

Hi! I need some new help since the code below isn't working for me. It's this that isn't working
    `xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" and "x:div[@id='mbContent']"`
I think it's because I'm using a CMS tool that has a proxy module that not accept this code for some strange reason. Therefore I'm looking for some alternative solution to add CLASS or ID and also add values to DIV elements by using this instead `xsl:apply-templates select="//*[@id='mbSubMenu']"` and also use copy as in the example below? Preciate some new help! Thanks! :)

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431330/css-style-and-xslt).

Answer (score 1):

The Xpath used in the expression is fine until you are using 'x' as xmlns in the XSLT document.

The template will match for the `<div>` provided its id is `mbContent` and the selected context will have all the descendents.

You can change the inline CSS for the elements. Since you said that this part is going to be within some other XHTML document. You can choose XML as output.
Change the inline CSS if you want to.
You can also assign them different classes so that it takes global styles automatically.

The idea is that given a XML document you are transforming it to another XML document.
Therefore, you can apply styles as you like it.

I hope that answers your question.

P.S. use proper xmlns in the XPath expression.

Let's assume following is the HTML doc.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mbContent">
        <div>
            <span>Some complex structure</span>
        </div>    
    </div>
</body>
```

Apply the following XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
exclude-result-prefixes="x">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="x:div[@id='mbContent']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:text>someNewStyle</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This will result in the following output.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="someNewStyle" id="mbContent">
        <div>
            <span>Some complex structure</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

You can change the XSL to suit your need.

Regards,

Ravish.

Comment: Thanks, despite that I use xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" I get contents outside DIV mbContent.(Only in text) How can I apply inline styles to this DIV?

Comment: Answering your comment question on on content outside DIV mbContent (only in Text): This seems to be the output of the standard in-built template. To avoid this, be sure to catch anything else with an empty template like <xsl:template match="*" /> at the end of your XSLT code.

Comment: When I try the code above in the browser and then look at the source, there is no class="someNewStyle" added!? I put this line of code <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transform.xsl"?> on the first row of the HTML soucre? Is this the only way transform a XHTML document by inserting a reference inside the actual XHTML document? I was hoping you you could read or link in the source in some other way if both the XSL file and the XHTML file was on the same folder on a server? Preciate answer to my comment! :)

Comment: In addition to adding <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transform.xsl"?> in the XHTML file you'll also need to add <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> on top of the file. It has to be an XML file. Now if you try to open the XML file in the browser it will show you the desired output.